# HTML 5 video player with custom controller?

Tags: video

How to create Html 5 video using custom controllers?
`<video><source src="file path" type="video/mp4"></source></video>`

Comment: Maybe [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos) can help you?

Answer (score 0):

### /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Author:Shrikant Adsule

|
| *Feel free to edit.
| *add font Awesome for video menu and its related Fonts folder too
| *font Awesome css link presented at html file
---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

------------------------CSS------------------------

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
.main {
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
} 
.controls {
  margin: 20px 0 -51px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 38px;
  width: 560px;
  padding: 15px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#video {
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 150px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: black;
}
.media {
  left: 95px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  // height: 26px;
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffa500;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.media:hover {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 2px red;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#totalTime {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  right: 33px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 1px red;
  padding: 4px;
}
#elapsedTime {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  left: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 1px red;
  padding: 4px;
}
#rightListBar {
  float: right;
  height: 625px;
  width: 400px;
  border-left: 2px solid @veryDarkGray;
  border-radius: 0;
}
#item {
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: absolute;
  height: 625px;
  width: 395px;
  /*border-bottom: 2px solid #707070;*/
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#item img {
  width: 80px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px @veryDarkGray;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px;
}
#item a:hover {
  text-shadow: 1px 0 red;
}
.innerdiv a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px 0 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#splayer {
  height: 480;
}
#progress,
#volumeDiv {
  margin-top: 3px;
  right: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  /*border-radius: 10px;*/
  border: 1px solid #ffa500;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #ffa500;
}
#volumeDiv,
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}    
#cross {
  color: #ffa500;
}
#volumeDiv {
  width: 20%;
}
#movebar,
#volume {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: #46ed78;
  /*box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 10px 5px red;*/
  /*border-radius: 8px;*/
}
.setting{
  color:#ffa500;
  float: right;
}
.setting:hover{
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 2px red;
}
```

-------------------End CSS-----------------------------

------------------HTML---------------------------------

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>.COM</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/font-    awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/design.scss">
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  <div id="video">
    <video id="splayer" preload="metadata" width=580 onloadedmetadata="setDuration()" ontimeupdate="updateTime()">
      <source src="../media/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
      <strong>Player does not support this file type.</strong>
    </video>
    <label id="elapsedTime">0</label>

    <div id="progress">
      <div id="movebar"></div>
    </div>
    <label id="totalTime">0</label>

    <div class="controls" id="controls">
      <a href="javascript:plays()"><i class='media fa fa-play-circle'></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:pauses()"><i class='media fa fa-pause'></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:stops()"><i class='media fa fa-stop-circle'></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:rewind()"><i class='media fa fa-backward fa-2x'></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:forwards()"><i class='media fa fa-forward fa-2x'></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:fullScreen()"><i class='media fa fa-expand fa-2x'></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:smallScreen()"><i class='media fa fa-compress fa-2x'></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:muteVolume()" id="volumeOff"><i class='media fa fa-volume-off fa-2x'></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:changeVolume('-');setTimeout(hideVolume, 6000);" id="volumeDown"><i class='media fa fa-volume-down fa-2x'></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

      <div id="volumeDiv">
        <div id="volume">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:changeVolume('+');setTimeout(hideVolume, 6000);" id="volumeUp"><i class='media fa fa-volume-up fa-2x'></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

    </div>
    <div class="setting">
      <a href="javascript:settings()"><i class="setting fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="rightListBar">
</div>
<script src='../js/video.js'></script>
</div>
```

---------------------End HTML------------------

------------------JS---------------------------

```
// Load the list of items to play video

var video = document.getElementById("splayer");
var arr = [
  "'../media/sintel.mp4'",
  "'../media/Arnold.MP4'",
  "'../media/sanam puri songs (ACOUSTIC) - YouTube.mp4'",
  "'../media/big_buck_bunny.mp4'",
  "'../media/102614-maui-with-words.webm'",
  "'../media/Dream - Motivational Video - YouTube.MKV'",
  "'../media/My Top 5 Life Inspirational Songs - YouTube.MKV'",
  "'../media/BEST Fitness Motivation Video HD !!! - POWER REEL -     YouTube.MKV'",
  "'../media/BELIEVE IN YOURSELF - Motivational Video (ft. Jaret     Grossman & Eric Thomas) - YouTube.MKV'",
  "'../media/Jai Hanuman gyan gun sagar with lyrics! - YouTube.MKV'",
  "'../media/missile.mp4'",
  "'../media/mov_bbb.mp4'"
];
var id = document.getElementById('rightListBar');
// var imgdiv=document.getElementById('itemImage');
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id', 'item');
id.appendChild(div);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var innerdiv = document.createElement('div');
  innerdiv.setAttribute('class', 'innerdiv');
  div.appendChild(innerdiv);
  var image = document.createElement('img');
  image.setAttribute('src', '../images/image3.jpg');
  innerdiv.appendChild(image);
  var anchor = document.createElement('a');
  // anchor.setAttribute('onclick','selectItemToPlay('+arr[i]+')')
  anchor.setAttribute('onclick', 'selectItemToPlay(' + arr[i] + ')');
  var str = arr[i].substr(10);
  item = str.substr(0, str.length - 5);
  anchor.innerHTML = item;
  innerdiv.appendChild(anchor);
}

function selectItemToPlay(item) {
  var video = document.getElementById("splayer");
  stops();
  video.src = item;
  plays();
}

var string;

function shuffleList() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    string = arr[i];
    string.substr(0, length - 3);
    video.src = string;
    video.play();
  }
}

function setDuration() {
  var totalLength = video.duration;
  totalLength = totalLength / 60;
  document.getElementById('totalTime').innerHTML =     totalLength.toFixed(2).replace('.', ':');
}

var pbar = document.getElementById('movebar');

function updateTime() {
  var playingSpot = video.currentTime;
  var m = playingSpot / 60;
  m = m.toFixed(2)
  document.getElementById('elapsedTime').innerHTML = m.replace('.', ':');
  // var r = video.buffered;
  // var start = r.start(0);
  // var end = r.end(0);
  var total = video.duration;
  var percentage = Math.floor((100 / total) * playingSpot);
  pbar.innerHTML = percentage + '%';
  pbar.style.width = percentage + '%';
}

function plays() {
  video.play();
}

function pauses() {
  video.paused === true ? video.play() : video.pause();
}

function forwards() {
  video.currentTime += 5;
}

function rewind() {
  video.currentTime -= 5;
}

function stops() {
  video.pause();
  video.currentTime = 0;
}
var vbar = document.getElementById('volume');
var vdiv = document.getElementById('volumeDiv');
var volumeDown = document.querySelector('#volumeDown');
var volumeUp = document.querySelector('#volumeUp');
var volumeOff = document.querySelector('#volumeOff');

function changeVolume(direction) {
  if (direction === '+') {
    video.volume += video.volume == 1 ? 0 : 0.1;
    console.log(video.volume);
    vbar.innerHTML = Math.round(video.volume * 10);
    vbar.style.width = Math.round(video.volume * 10) * 10 + '%';
    vdiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    video.volume -= (video.volume == 0 ? 0 : 0.1);
    console.log(video.volume);

    vbar.innerHTML = Math.round(video.volume * 10);
    vbar.style.width = Math.round(video.volume * 10) * 10 - 10 + '%';
    vdiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  video.volume = parseFloat(video.volume).toFixed(1);
  // setTimeout('hideVolume',3000);
}

function hideVolume() {
  vdiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function muteVolume() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('volumeOff');
  if (video.muted) {
    video.muted = false;
    btn.style.textDecoration = "none";
  } else {
    video.muted = true;
    btn.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    btn.style.color = "red";
    btn.style.transform = "rotate(-7deg)"
  }
}

var controldiv = document.getElementById('controls');
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');

function fullScreen() {
  video.width = 800;
  controldiv.style.width = '780px';
  progress.style.right = '113px';
  // btns.style.left='210px';
}

function smallScreen() {
  video.width = 580;
  controldiv.style.width = '560px';
  controldiv.style.margin = '20px 0 -51px 0px';
  progress.style.right = '75px';
}

var progressBarXY = document.querySelector('#progress');
var movePBar = document.querySelector('#movebar')

progressBarXY.addEventListener("click", forwardBackwardVideoPosition,     false);

function forwardBackwardVideoPosition(e) {
   video.currentTime = (e.offsetX / progressBarXY.clientWidth) *     video.duration;
  video.paused = video.play();
}

function getPosition(element) {
  var posX = 0;
  var posY = 0;

  while (element) {
    posX += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft +     element.clientLeft);
    posY += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
    element = element.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: posX,
    y: posY
  };
}
```

-----------------------End JS-------------------------